# Edit MP4 metadata using MediaCodec API

Tags: android, mp4, android-mediacodec, video-editing

Android SDK provides class [MediaMetadataRetriever](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html) for extracting metadata from MP4 files. Is there a way to edit MP4 metadata fields using MediaCodec API (without ffmpeg)? My task is to reset [rotation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_ROTATION) field.

Comment: MediaCodec doesn't operate at that level. You need a higher-level API, such as MediaMuxer, which includes the `setOrientationHint()` method. That class is only for creating files though, not editing them.

Comment: Hey @fadden, thanks for your answer. Do you know any other way to edit MP4 metadata without using ffmpeg?

Comment: HEy did you find the solution? I have a same issue

Comment: Hi @iMDroid. I did, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33278167/3292393

Answer (score 1):

[mp4parser](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser) seems to be what you are looking for, although I'm not certain where exactly the rotation field is located in the MP4 (I don't know enough about the file layout). If you know which box (or "atom") the metadata is stored in, then the [MetaDataRead](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser/blob/20d6b28804020b29a3dd5f34228fc7e15f25837c/examples/src/main/java/com/googlecode/mp4parser/stuff/MetaDataRead.java) and [MetaDataInsert](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser/blob/20d6b28804020b29a3dd5f34228fc7e15f25837c/examples/src/main/java/com/googlecode/mp4parser/stuff/MetaDataInsert.java) classes are pretty clear examples of how to read and write the data (they specifically work on the iTunes "Name"/"Title" field, but writing other metadata works the same way, once you know where it should be located). Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @monkey_05_06, thanks for your answer. I've tried to use mp4parser for this task but I've met some issues with understanding how meta information is storing in MP4 format and how to securely extract it. So, I found an alternative solution how to reset rotation, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242851/change-rotation-in-mediaformat