# Change rotation in MediaFormat

Tags: android, mp4, android-mediacodec, video-editing

In Android API 23 [MediaFormat.KEY_ROTATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaFormat.html#KEY_ROTATION) field was introduced. Is there any way to change rotation in MediaFormat on earlier Android versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the working solution:

```
MediaFormat mediaformat;
// ...
mediaformat.setInteger("rotation-degrees", 0)
```

Comment: MediaFormat.KEY_ROTATION constant is available only for Android 6.0 and higher. If you want to control rotation in earlier versions of Android, you should use it by value "rotation-degrees"

Comment: how do you change rotation-degrees value in metadata for particular mp4 file which is already recorded.Any idea?

Comment: @Droidwala Were you able to change the rotation?

Comment: @ravi If you are asking about the changing rotation degrees using the method mentioned in answer? Then, no. If you are trying to change the metadata of already recorded file then maybe you should check out [mp4Parser lib](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser)

Comment: @Droidwala Thanks for your response. I am trying to change the rotation of a recorded MP4 file without any libraries.

Comment: @PunitD A little bit late response. All videos taken by Android have landscape orientation. Depending on value of 'rotation' metadata field a video player will render it in correct orientation while playing. The question has been asked regarding to how to change the value of this field of a video file when it is being saved on the disk. If you want to rotate the source video, e.g. you have 1920x1080 and you want to make it 1080x1920 with rotating the picture, you need to redecode it with some decoding library or a video editor. This operation is time and resources consuming.

Comment: KEY_ROTATION is not rotating decoded frames rendered on a Surface. I'm testing on Samsung Galaxy Note 10. Any help how to use KEY_ROTATION properly